# Could I detect guitar chords/notes via comparing it to other notes?

Tags: python, audio, pattern-recognition

My idea is that instead of using DFT/FFT to calculate guitar chords or notes, I can attempt a different approach. How I plan to do it is so (in Python)

1. Record myself playing a large range of notes and chords and store them as a large dataset.
2. After this, I would create another recording of me doing a single note or chord which needs to be recognised.
3. In a similar manner of which I compare two datasets using spearman's rank correlation coefficient, I could compare the recording to each file in the dataset and see which note or chord is most similar.

For my situation, I aim for this calculation to occur as I play, so no preprocessing would be involved. To do this I would need to calibrate the background noise volume, so I could distinct each note/chord from each other.

**Diagram to explain the concept:** 
To help explain my idea, I have created a simple image which has a dataset of two notes. 
[Imgur link of the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8ubb.jpg)

My question is how viable this would be, and if it is feasible, how would I conduct it in Python?

Thanks,
Aj.

Comment: One big problem is that, at the level of time-domain samples, any direct comparison such as squared difference or correlation is very sensitive to the precise time alignment between the signals: correlating a sinusoid against itself but delayed by 1/4 cycle will give zero correlation. That's the advantage of using the Fourier transform magnitude - it's effectively invariant to phase shifts.

Comment: Check out: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/key-chord-recognition-using-a-computer